# Generate compatible Hash for Swift and PHP

Tags: php, swift, rest, hash

I want to create a password hash from PHP and Swift which should be compatible.
What can be used to achieve that goal? I don't want to send the password in plaintext.

Some Background information:
I want a login with a hashed password in the database. This login shall be used from PHP and via REST API from Swift. I could use MD5 but MD5 isn't really secure.
For password_verify (php) I need also the plaintext password, to verify it.

Comment: A little addition: the api is located in a local network, that means just a self signed certificate is an option. Think ATS will prevent a connection with a self signed certificate?

Comment: Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you but does it have todo with my question? I'm asking for a possibility to send a hashed password to an API instead of sending plaintext password. A hash which can be used to compare sent and saved hash server sided. password_verify needs a plaintext password. I think there is no possibility? After some researches I found out that mostly password is sent plaintext over https.

Comment: There is an assumption in the question that you are interested in secure password handling. Passwords should be sent from a client to to server should be sent in plain text over a HTTS connection and saved in the server with `password_hash` (if using PHP). Sending a hashed password does no help, if an attacker can see the hashed password he just uses it to access the server. Without a secure connection other options include [CHAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-Handshake_Authentication_Protocol).

Comment: Sounds plausible. Thanks.